# How to make javascript function always re-execute on scroll and follow width of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, math

I want to make randomString() function to always re-execute on window movement (scroll) and to display the output within the width and height of the div="randlock" element. Currently the output is displayed but only once and always beyond the set width.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function randomString() {
        var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        var string_length = 300;
        var randomstring = '';
        for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
            var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
            randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
        }

        document.getElementById('randlock').innerHTML = randomstring;
        document.getElementById('randlock').style.width = "200px";  // this is not working
    });

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        randomString();
    })
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    #randlock {
        height: 300px;
        width: 200px;
    }
</style>
<div id="randlock">
</div>
```

To give more insight to what effect I'm trying to achieve please check crashplan.com/business/overview.html and scroll to the padlock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`randomString()` is declared incorrectly and you need to wrap your `scroll` event on the window object in a `document.ready` declaration. The overflowing text is nothing to do with the fixed width of the div. I've added `word-wrap: break-word` to the css in the example below which will fix this. Try the code below

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function randomString() {
        var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        var string_length = 300;
        var randomstring = '';
        for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
           var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
           randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
        }
        document.getElementById('randlock').innerHTML = randomstring;
    }

    $(function () { //Shorthand for $(document).ready(
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            randomString();
         });
    });
</script>

 <style type="text/css">
 #randlock {
        height: 300px;
        width: 200px;
        word-wrap: break-word;
 }
 </style>
<div id="randlock">
</div>
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5VCS9/3/)

Comment: Amazing, this works 100% as I intended it. But the width is still not working, the output goes beyond the 200px width. Do you know how can I fix the width too?

Comment: Thanks a lot, you've saved me hours of headaches, it's exactly as I wanted it now.